# Function working with an existing hook, doesn't work using it a custom do_action hook

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I know that add_action is used to call a function at the location of a hook. I used add_action like below and it gives me the output I need (Which is the price of a product in WooCommerce):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
```

I used the above code inside a custom plugin that i built.

But now I want the price to appear in a different location. I read about do_action and I learned that it is used to make new hooks.

So I made a new hook like below -

```
do_action('unique_mycustom_hook');
```

The new hook is kept inside "content-single-product.php" inside Woocommerce template folder.

And then I called my function at my new hook using the code below inside my plugin file.

```
add_action( 'unique_mycustom_hook', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
```

But this time I am NOT getting any output!

Do you have any idea why add_action worked in the pre-existing woocommerce hook but did not work in my new hook made using do_action?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE - 
I am adding more information on request.**

The purpose of my hook in woocommerce is to have the price of the product appear in a fixed sidebar. So I made a `<div>` section inside the file `"content-single-product.php"` inside WooCommerce template folder. This is the exact code that I added to the woocommerce template.

```
<div class="this_sidebar_is_fixed">
   <?php
      do_action('unique_mycustom_hook');
   ?>
</div>
```

Then I am calling the hook using a custom plugin I have.

Still it is not working.

Comment: Please the best thing is to include all the code of the template with your do_action() inside in the desired location… I can't help only with that information.

Comment: Dude but you wont believe it, i RESOLVED my problem only with your comment. I just had to move the do_action from content-single-product.php to variable.php and now its working! But can you maybe post an answer with the reason why it worked? I am new to hooks and filters.

Comment: Accepted that answer. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because location is also important depending on what you are hooking. 
 `woocommerce_before_variations_form` is located on `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` template inside a form.

So for example if you place your `unique_mycustom_hook` outside this form (or in another template), it will not work. That are the main reasons… They can be others too.

***---- updated ----***

Inside `content-single-product.php` your `do_action('unique_mycustom_hook');` can't work, because it needs to be located inside the form in `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`…

Comment: Hey I will update the question now. Gimme a minute. Would appreciate if you check again in 5 minutes